# C# MVC - jquery/bootstrap not found when being renderd

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# MVC project, I'm trying to render in bootstrap and jquery but once the page is loaded the scripts are not found.

Here is how I am rendering them in:

**_Layout.cshtml:**

```
<head>
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
</head>
```

**BundleConfig.cs:**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                 "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"
                  ));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/jquery.min.js",
                 "~/Scripts/jquery.js"
                 ));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/tether.min.js",
                 "~/Scripts/tether.js",                 
                 "~/Scripts/apexcharts.min.js",
                 "~/Scripts/layout.js"
                 ));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                "~/Content/layout.css",
                "~/Content/Style.css"
                ));
```

**In developer tools:**

[image: In dev tools]

I have the scripts in my Scripts folder in MVC. Why aren't they being loaded in?

Comment: `/~/` doesnt look right in that console log.

Comment: Have you installed Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization? PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization

Comment: @momo I have installed the optimization

Comment: Did you add BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; in the RegisterBundles(...) method located in BundleConfig.cs?

Comment: My layout file has these lines towards the bottom of the body as well:   `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap") // line is not in head tag
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)</body>`